# Separating last indexes into another column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, indexing

I have the following dataset on chips in a store

| STORE_NBR | PROD_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt 175g |
| 1307 | Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken170g |

and want to make the weight in grams of my chips in its own column. This is a sample of a very large data set over 100,000 rows. Originally i separated it out by the last space, but noticed the weight didn't always have a space between the product name and weight.

The ideal output is:

| PROD_NAME | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt | 175g |
| Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken | 170g |

The original line of code was:
df_transactions[['PROD_NAME', 'Weight']] = df_transactions['PROD_NAME'].str.rsplit(" ", n=1, expand=True)

so I updated it to:
df_transactions[['PROD_NAME','Size']] = df_transactions['PROD_NAME'].str.rsplit("\d{3}g", n=1, expand=True)

I keep getting the error "Columns must be same length as key."
an someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or another way to split off the weight?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
out = df['PROD_NAME'].str.extract(r'^(?P<PROD_NAME>.*?)\s*(?P<Weight>\d+g)$')
```

Output:

```
                          PROD_NAME Weight
0      CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt   175g
1  Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken   170g
```

###### regex

```
^                     # match start of string
(?P<PROD_NAME>.*?)    # capture everything (non greedy)
\s*                   # optional spaces
(?P<Weight>\d+g)      # capture digits followed by "g"
$                     # match end of string
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkEWgm/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'STORE_NBR': [1000, 1307],
                    'PROD_NAME': ['CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt 175g', 'Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken170g']})

def extract_weight_regex(row):
    # Match digits followed by "g" at the end
  match = re.search(r"\d+g$", row['PROD_NAME']) 
  if match:
    weight = match.group()
    """print(weight)
    print(row['PROD_NAME'][:-len(weight)])
    175g
   CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt 
   170g
   Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken"""
    return row['PROD_NAME'][:-len(weight)], weight 
  else:
    return row['PROD_NAME'], None  


df[['PROD_NAME', 'Weight']] = df.agg(extract_weight_regex, axis=1, result_type='expand')

"""print(df)
   STORE_NBR                         PROD_NAME Weight
0       1000     CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt    175g
1       1307  Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken   170g
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code**

use `str.split` instead rsplit and fix your regex pattern

```
pat = '\s*(?=\d+g$)'
df_transactions[['PROD_NAME','Size']] = df_transactions['PROD_NAME'].str.split(pat, n=1, expand=True)
```

df_transactions:

```
    STORE_NBR   PROD_NAME                           Size
0   1000        CNatural Chip Compny SeaSalt        175g
1   1307        Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken    170g
```